# Set focus on column - Ag Grid React

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

When we have 200 Columns in an Ag-grid and the user wants to look for a particular column, normally it is done by scrolling and looking for that column but having 200+ columns is going to be annoying.

So we need to develop and search box to search for the column name we scroll and set focus on the given column.

> What I have tried

The following code does focus but only on visible columns, if I have to focus on the 100th Column it doesn't work

```
gridRef.current.api.setFocusedCell(0,gridRef.current.columnApi.columnModel.getAllDisplayedColumns()[10]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below method [`ensureColumnVisible`](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/documentation/javascript/grid-api/)to make sure the column is visible.

```
const allColumns = params.columnApi.getAllColumns();
console.log(allColumns);
params.api.ensureColumnVisible(allColumns[allColumns.length - 1].colId); // <- changed here
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-infinite-scroll-example-acfqu8)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried implementing this but the focus still not scrolling to a given column, even in the stackblitz given it isn't going to last but one column according to the code

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G Please check the stackblitz again, I think I posted the wrong link the first time!